# Number series problem

Tags: prime-numbers

Find the missing number in the series ?

$$6,49,305,?,6179,18560,37147$$

Comment: 36579815457466500227. No results on OEIS, as far as my search goes.

Comment: Any series can be completed by inserting any number. I could just claim those are what a polynomial of degree $n-1$ goes through on the first $n$ integers, with $n$ the number of points I have given.

Comment: Did I guess it right ?

Answer (score 2):

$$6\cdot 7+7=49$$

$$49\cdot 6+11=305$$

$$305\cdot 5+15=\color\red {1540}$$

$$\color\red {1540}\cdot 4+19=6179$$

$$6179\cdot 3+23=18560$$

$$18560\cdot 2+27=37147$$

Comment: The patterns in $7,6,5,4,3,2$ and $7,11,15,19,23,27$ are not too hard to find :)